# How to split array in every negative number

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers

I have an array of number like this

```
   number = [4, -1, 6, -2, 3, 5, -7, 7]
```

Is there any way to split it when meets negative value?

So, it will be like this

```
array = [[4], [-1], [6], [-2], [3,5], [-7], [7]]
```

I think it can be done using regex, but I still not found it

Thanks

Comment: No, certainly not using a regex. Just loop over the array and append the element to a the last array or create a new one depending on the value.

Comment: @luk2302 Oh nice, I will try it first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First create a few `temporary` **arrays** to hold the value(s).
2. `Loop` through your **main array**.
3. Then check if the number is `greater` than **zero**.

   Add the positive number to the newly created temporary array.

   Also, check for the last element and push it into the output array as
   required.
4. In the else part check for the element `less` then **zero**

   Then first, push the temporary array for positive number into in output array.

   After that push the negative number temporary array for negative numbers.

   Push that temporary array for negative numbers into the output array.

   Now, reset the temporary array for both positive and negative numbers.

```js
let number = [4, -1, 6, -2, 3, 5, -7, 7];

let array = [];
let tempArr = [];
let tempArrForNeg = [];
let numberLength = number.length;

for(let i = 0; i < numberLength; i++){
   
   if(number[i] > 0){
     tempArr.push(number[i]);
     if(i === (numberLength - 1))
       array.push(tempArr);
   }
   else{
    array.push(tempArr);
    tempArrForNeg.push(number[i]);
    
    array.push(tempArrForNeg);
    tempArr = [];
    tempArrForNeg = [];
   }
}

console.log(array);

//[[4], [-1], [6], [-2], [3,5], [-7], [7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var number= [1,-2,5,6,2,-2,-3,-4,5];
console.log(splitByPositivity(number));

function splitByPositivity(numArr) {
  var newArr = []
  var tempArr = [numArr[0]];
  for (var i=1;i<numArr.length;i++){
    if (numArr[i]>0&&tempArr[tempArr.length-1]>0||numArr[i]<0&&tempArr[tempArr.length-1]<0)
       tempArr.push(numArr[i])
    else{
       newArr.push(tempArr)
       tempArr = [numArr[i]];
}
  }
newArr.push(tempArr);
return newArr;
}
```

Pay attention you need to handle 0 value. It is not nagitive and not positive